# rails 4 devise ldap_authenticatable current_user not set

Tags: devise

I'm fairly new to Rails 4 and am experimenting with Devise and ldap_authenticatable and I see something that I'm not sure is right. When I authenticate to my Active Directory Devise works fine and stores the user in the MySQL database as expected.  However, I seem to lose the user params and can't tell which user just authenticated.  user_signed_in? returns false but if I hit the login link I get the message "already signed in"  current_user is nil and set_user fails because params(:id) is nil.  Seems like something is broken here but I'm not sure what the norm is as far as Devise setting or keeping user params alive.
Any ideas or helpful information? 
User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :ldap_authenticatable, :trackable, :validatable
  before_save :get_ldap_attrs
def get_ldap_attrs
  self.firstname = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.email, 'givenName')
  self.lastname = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.email, 'sn')
  self.login = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.email, 'sAMAccountName')
  self.email = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.email,'mail').first
  self.studentid = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.email, 'title')
end
end
----

    ldap.yaml
    ## Authorizations
    # Uncomment out the merging for each environment that you'd like to include.
    # You can also just copy and paste the tree (do not include the "authorizations") to each
    # environment if you need something different per enviornment.
    authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
      allow_unauthenticated_bind: false
      group_base: ou=groups,dc=kentshill,dc=org
      ## Requires config.ldap_check_group_membership in devise.rb be true
      # Can have multiple values, must match all to be authorized
      required_groups:
        # If only a group name is given, membership will be checked against "uniqueMember"
        #- ######################## 
        #- #######################
        # If an array is given, the first element will be the attribute to check against, the second the group name
        #- ["moreMembers", "cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com"]
      ## Requires config.ldap_check_attributes in devise.rb to be true
      ## Can have multiple attributes and values, must match all to be authorized
      require_attribute:
        objectClass: inetOrgPerson
        authorizationRole: postsAdmin

    ## Environment

    development:
      host: address
      port: 636
      attribute: mail
      base: DN
      admin_user: fqn user with privs
      admin_password: password
      ssl: true
      # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS

    test:
      host: localhost
      port: 3389
      attribute: cn
      base: ou=people,dc=test,dc=com
      admin_user: cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
      admin_password: admin_password
      ssl: simple_tls
      # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS

    production:
      host: localhost
      port: 636
      attribute: cn
      base: ou=people,dc=test,dc=com
      admin_user: cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
      admin_password: admin_password
      ssl: start_tls
      # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
    ----------------
    Devise initializer
    # Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
    # Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
    Devise.setup do |config|
      # ==> LDAP Configuration
      config.ldap_logger = true
      config.ldap_create_user = true
      config.ldap_update_password = true
      #config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
      config.ldap_check_group_membership = false
      #config.ldap_check_group_membership_without_admin = false
      config.ldap_check_attributes = false
      config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
      config.ldap_ad_group_check = false

      # The secret key used by Devise. Devise uses this key to generate
      # random tokens. Changing this key will render invalid all existing
      # confirmation, reset password and unlock tokens in the database.
      # Devise will use the `secret_key_base` on Rails 4+ applications as its `secret_key`
      # by default. You can change it below and use your own secret key.
      # config.secret_key = 'ead157a98cc1402f93c717c537225a807971f381bdb51063b22d9979b39e0db385493e0d392999152597ce52baf327d97ffc9a59371ea3258cd8f5fc6d158b75'

      # ==> Mailer Configuration
      # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
      # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class
      # with default "from" parameter.
      config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'

      # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
      # config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'

      # ==> ORM configuration
      # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
      # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
      # available as additional gems.
      require 'devise/orm/active_record'
      config.ldap_auth_username_builder = Proc.new() { |attribute, login, ldap| login }
    #  config.warden do |manager|
    #    manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :ldap_authenticatable
    #  end

      # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
      # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
      # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
      # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
      # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
      # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
      # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
      # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
      config.authentication_keys = [:email]

      # Configure parameters from the request object used for authentication. Each entry
      # given should be a request method and it will automatically be passed to the
      # find_for_authentication method and considered in your model lookup. For instance,
      # if you set :request_keys to [:subdomain], :subdomain will be used on authentication.
      # The same considerations mentioned for authentication_keys also apply to request_keys.
      # config.request_keys = []

      # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
      # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
      # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
      config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
    "config/initializers/devise.rb" 280L, 13721C
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: No problem showing code.  Not sure what would be most helpful.

Comment: Figured it out.  I had a before_filter :authenticate_user! in my application controller which logged in users but when the app switched to another controller the current_user went away.  Removed the filter from the application controller - it was already also in the users controller - and it now works.